# How to achieve conditional layout based on URL with Sveltekit

Tags: html, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

To preface this post I am very new to svelte and am struggling to find documentation regarding this issue. Any help is appreciated.

I am building a website that serves as a host for other demo sites with sveltekit (& typescript). I have the main site's default navigation bar and footer elements inside the root +layout.svelte file in my project.

I am attempting to have the default nav/footer display based on the condition that the user is not currently viewing a demo site. If the user is on a demo site, I want a demo navigation bar (a separate component) and no footer to display instead.

The user is able to navigate to a demo from the links provided in the default navigation component. This all works fine on desktop, but on mobile both the layouts load on the same page. Meaning, that the demo site loads with the default navigation and footer, and then below that loads again with the demo navigation.

I'm assuming something is wrong with my logic leading to this double loading. If you have any suggestions on how to fix my logic or a better way to implement a conditional layout I would appreciate the help.

Currently, I have a reactive boolean variable that reflects whether the user is currently in the '/demos/' route defined in the script tags of the root +layout.svelte (an example of the route would be 'www.websitename.com/demos/test1')

```
import { page } from '$app/stores';
let isDemoUrl: boolean;
$: isDemoUrl = $page.url.pathname.startsWith('/demos/');
```

The actual layout portion of the file is:

```
{#if !isDemoUrl}
  <DefaultNav />
  <slot />
  <DefaultFooter />
{:else}
  <DemoNav />
  <slot />
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to just use `+layout.svelte` files for that, they apply to all routes in the directory they are placed in. You can also break out of layouts using `@` and create groups using `(...)` (they apply a layout without adding a segment to the URL path). See the advanced routing documentation [on layouts](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts).

You could create a group for the rest of your application with the regular layout and have a base layout that is just `<slot />`:

```
src/routes/
├ (app)/
│ ├ ... other routes here
│ └ +layout.svelte | layout for rest of application
├ demos/
│ └ ... demo routes here
└ +layout.svelte | just <slot />
```